# How to iterate some models [I can't understand]

Tags: templates, ember.js, models, ember-cli

When I use the Ember inspector I can look at my three models with their data.

[image]

How can I use an `each` in my template? Something like this: `{{#each item model.entry}}`

I'm using RestAdapter

This is my route

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from '../config/environment';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.find('entry') 
  }
});
```

Comment: @AJ Gregory Thank you, I am from Colombia and I am learning English, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Your model itself is a collection of `entry` records. You should be able to iterate through them on your template like this:

```
{{#each entry in model}}
  *you can use entry here*
{{/each}}
```

Comment: That isn't was the problem, but thank you for your time

Comment: Since I, too, understood this to be the problem, maybe you can elaborate (e. g. with a live example of what's working and a comment, what's not in a http://emberjs.jsbin.com/?html,css,js,output) ...